# generating dummy variables for n largest values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dummy-variable

I have a database that is built like so:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4],'value':[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,1]})

>>> df

    id  value    
0   1      1    
1   1      2    
2   1      3    
3   2      1    
4   2      2    
5   2      3    
6   2      4    
7   3      1    
8   4      1
```

and I want to generate a dummy variable for the nth largest values per ID (here for n=2) so that it's equal for 1 for all the values that are one of the nth highest value:

```
    id  value  Largest 
0   1      1     0    
1   1      2     1    
2   1      3     1    
3   2      1     0    
4   2      2     0    
5   2      3     1    
6   2      4     1    
7   3      1     1    
8   4      1     1
```

I've tried:

```
df['highest'] = 0
df['highest'].loc[df['value'].isin(df.groupby(['id'])['value'].nlargest(1))] = 1
```

but that would misatribute values from one ID if that happened to be the highest values in another ID

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried? What did not work? Please include your code and full error messages, if any.

Comment: I'd say rather than creating a dummy variable, you should apply a function and set the n as a parameter for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***Setup***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4],'value':[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,1]})
n = 2
```

#### Using `nlargest` and `loc`:

```
df['flag'] = 0
df.loc[df.groupby('id').value.nlargest(n).index.get_level_values(1), 'flag'] = 1
```

#### Using `np.where` and `assign`:

This avoids modifying the DataFrame in place.

```
df.assign(
    flag=np.where(
        df.index.isin(df.groupby('id').value.nlargest(n).index.get_level_values(1)), 1, 0
    )
)
```

Both result in:

```
   id  value  flag
0   1      1     0
1   1      2     1
2   1      3     1
3   2      1     0
4   2      2     0
5   2      3     1
6   2      4     1
7   3      1     1
8   4      1     1
```

As @jezrael pointed out, `np.where` isn't really necessary here, since you are looking for binary results, and you can instead use:

```
df.assign(flag=df.index.isin(df.groupby('id').value.nlargest(n).index.get_level_values(1)).astype(int))
```

Comment: Better is `df.index.isin(df.groupby('id').value.nlargest(n).index.get_level_values(1)).astype(int)` ;)

Comment: @jezrael, it is helpful. What if I try to flag nlargest with condition? i.e. I want to flag 1 if values <nlargest otherwise flag 2?